# React.js useRef / createRef current is always null scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-ref

I have a problem with assigning reference to a div. I want to scroll to the div for this reference, but the value of .current, is always null/undefined.

```
import React, { Component, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {

    myRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    { this.myRef ? this.scrollToRef() : null }
  }

  scrollToRef = () => {
    if(this.myRef.current !== null) 
    // window.scrollTo(0, this.myRef.current.offsetTop);
    window.scrollTo({ behavior: 'smooth', top: this.myRef.current.offsetTop })
  }

  render() {
    return (
<Aux>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route
          path="/contact"
          render={() => (
            <Main
              page={<HomePage />}
              tools={<Toolbar />}
              content={
                <Contact ref={this.myRef} />
              }
            />
          )}
        />
      </BrowserRouter>
</Aux>
    );
  }
}
```

and inside Contact:

```
import React, { useRef, Component, createRef } from 'react';
import classes from './contact.module.css';

const contact = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const newRef = useRef();
  return <div className={classes.Contact} ref={ref}>{props.children}</div>
};
```

I've tried many versions of this and .current is always empty..

[image]

React: 16.13.1
I'd like to scroll to the `<div className={classes.Contact} ref={ref}>` when I click on Contact at toolbar.

EDIT:
Right now at `scrollToRef()` I have reference but `window.scrollTo()`still doesn't work.. Is it possible that hoc `<Aux>` harming something? Maybe problem is with re-rendering DOM? Earlier I've tried to use ease-out effect but it also didn't work correctly. It run when I unclick checkbox during debugging but didn't fire when I open new overlap.

Answer (score 0):

you pass to the function `setRef` the variable `(newRef)`, but in the function definition you wrote `(props)` as the variable. so you need to change the function to:

```
  setReference = (newRef) => {
    this.setState({myRef: newRef})
  }
```

i hope that it will help :)

and by the way you better use `forwardRef` - https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: I changed that earlier, but forgot to paste it here. Thanks, but didn't help. Need to try forwardRef

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html), also, instead of calling functions in the jsx directly, use lifecycle hooks like [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Here's the code using a forwardRef, as you can see it's a simpler way of setting things up in this case.

```js
const Contact = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div className={'Contact'} ref={ref}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
});

class App extends React.Component {
  contactRef = React.createRef();
  state = {};

  scrollToRef = () => {
    if (this.contactRef.current !== null)
      // window.scrollTo(0, this.myRef.current.offsetTop);
      window.scrollTo({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        top: this.contactRef.current.offsetTop,
      });
    console.log(this.contactRef.current);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Contact ref={this.contactRef} />
        <button onClick={this.scrollToRef}>Scroll</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: According to @ינון רחמים link with forwardRef I changed my code but it still doesn't work. I've edited source code.

Comment: you supposed to pass the `myRef`  to the Contact component -
`<Contact ref={this.myRef} />`

Comment: I've Updated post

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem fixed.

I changed componentDidMount :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // { this.myRef ? this.scrollToRef() : null }
    this.myRef ? this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'center',
      inline: 'center'
    })
      : null
  }
```